# How can i set partition key from cosmosdb collection through entity framework core code first approach?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

public class TaxathandDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TaxathandDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

```
    protected TaxathandDbContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {                    
                OneCollectionPerDbSet(modelBuilder);
            }

    private void OneCollectionPerDbSet(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var dbSets = typeof(TaxathandDbContext).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && typeof(DbSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()));
        foreach (var dbSet in dbSets)
        {`enter code here`
            var metadata = modelBuilder.Entity(dbSet.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]).Metadata;
            metadata.Cosmos().ContainerName = dbSet.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#partition-keys) it is pretty simple. One important thing to note: **your partition keys must be string or [converted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) to string!**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<TodoItem>()
            .HasPartitionKey(o => o.Id);
}
```